# Responsive design, css

Tags: css, responsive

Estoy intentando ver si existe la posibilidad de que al ingresar a mi pagina web, no tenga el 50% de zoom. Sin la necesidad de hacer un media de 420px(ya que tengo mucho texto y se ve feo cuando sobrepasa los 500px)
https://jolly-creponne-d89dbc.netlify.app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la solución mas rápida para tu inconveniente seria que los textos escalaran según el ancho de tu pantalla así mientras la pantalla disminuya los textos mas grandes se adapten a ella:

```
font-size: 20vw
```

cambia las medidas de tus textos usando vw y no pixeles, lo que hace es que camia el tamaño según el ancho de la pantalla, así no tendrías que usar los mediaQuerys eso normalmente se usa para algo mas en general porque si dependes mucho de eso puede generar conflictos con otros estilos, además esta solución te puede funcionar por el momento, pero te recomiendo estudiar los flexbox en css, así lograras un diseño totalmente responsive-web-design de forma mas sencilla :).

aqui tienes un ejemplo mas completo para usar en tus textos:

```
.estilo-x {
    font-size: calc(1em + 1vw);
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
}
```